# Zip subdirectories based on find, -exec

Tags: find, zip

Here's what I would like to achieve: I have some directories, and subdirectories in them (which may have sub-subdirectories). In each subdirectory I want a zip file with contents of that particular directory.

find nicely finds my subdirectories:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d
```

but I have a hard time completing the

```
-exec zip ... \;
```

Would you be able to help me with that? I tried many combinations, can't figure it out. :(

For clarification, here's a tree.

```
├── DIR1
│   ├── FILE1
|   ├── FILE2
│   └── FILE3
├── FILE4
├── DIR2
│   ├── DIR3
│   │   ├── SUBDIR1
│   │   │   ├── SUBFILE1
│   │   │   ├── SUBSUBDIR1
│   │   │   │   ├── SUBSUBFILE1
│   │   │   │   └── SUBSUBFILE2
│   │   │   └── SUBSUBDIR1
│   │   │       ├── SUBSUBFILE3
│   │   │       └── SUBSUBFILE4
│   │   ├── FILE4
│   │   ├── FILE5
│   │   ├── FILE6
│   │   └── Zip file named DIR3.zip with FILE4, FILE5, FILE6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `-execdir` instead of `-exec` runs the command from the directory `find` is currently traversing, which makes this problem a little easier:

`find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -execdir zip -r {}.zip {} ';'`

Note that the string `{}` is interpreted by `find` as the current filename, and is relative when `-execdir` is used.

Comment: Hey, works great. Thanks! Tried something akin to that, with -execname, not sure why it did not work outf.